# How to get value of Claim list in C# to Call the IdentyServer3 method

Tags: c#, claims

I am using identity server3 for authentication using Open ID Connect.
If I create a C# Claim List, and I would like to get the value of some claims. What should I do?

Eg.

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("sub", subject));
        claims.Add(new Claim("email", email));
        claims.Add(new Claim("name", name));
        claims.Add(new Claim("id", id));
        claims.Add(new Claim("score", score));
```

I can't use claims.sub or claims:sub or claims:subject
I am doing the unit test and need to parse value via parameter into the method.The method is from identy Server3 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Models/Contexts/ProfileDataRequestContext.cs

```
public ProfileDataRequestContext(ClaimsPrincipal subject, Client client, string caller, IEnumerable<string> requestedClaimTypes = null){}

var ProfileDataRequestContext context = new ProfileDataRequestContext();
```

I don't really know how to call

```
context.Subject.GetGetSubjectId();
```

Comment: do you mean how to get the claim you just add? have you tried this: `this.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claimRecord => claimRecord.Type == "sub")`